# Azure mysql server portal shows 150 GB extra used space than actual db size

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-sql

I'm using azure mysql database, Azure portal shows total of 350 GB of used space but when I analyzed using schema inspector the total size used is 205 GB. what might be cause of extra storage.

My assumption are,

1. Azure redundancy
2. Server parameter value set to high
3. Due to cached data

If it's due to server parameter, what are the parameter values I need to reconsider ?

Comment: 4. They want you to pay for more RAM?

Comment: Can you see the disk space being used for the various logs?  Still, 145GB is much too high unless something is going wrong and spitting out lots of stuff.  Get access to the logs.